# How can I check all used space on filesystem in linux?

Tags: df, du

I've already tried **du-ch** , **df -h** and **df -h --total** but it all result to their specific size of folder. Need to know how can I get the total used space in human readable form. Hoping for your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Already used df -h --total but it says that df: unrecognized option `--total'

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's clarify a few things. When you do `df -h --total`, there are a few things that show virtual filesystems, such as `tmpfs` and `udev`. We don't exactly want that, but we want to know all *physical* filesystems.  As such, we want to filter out only `/dev` items:

```
$ df -h | grep '^/dev/'
/dev/sda1       110G   77G   29G  74% /
/dev/sdb6       399G  223G  157G  59% /mnt/HDD
```

But there's a problem, too: `-h`  gives us total in human-readable format. We can't really add up items that have letters in them. `grep` also can't perform calculations. Thus, instead lets use `awk` instead, with summing the 3rd column:

```
$ df --block-size=1 | awk '/^\/dev/{total+=$3}END{print total}'                                                          
320762605568
```

Great ! now we only need to find the human readable version of that number. We can always write code in awk to do that, but there already exists `numfmt` utility. So we can do this:

```
$ df --block-size=1 | awk '/^\/dev/{total+=$3}END{print total}' | numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7               
 299GiB
```

And that's how you have the total of all *physical* devices that are mounted ( which is what `df` shows by default).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it like so:

```
df -h --total / | grep total | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Or:

```
df -h --total . | grep total | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Result:

```
599G
```

Comment: What is the point of `--total` when specifying a single path? maybe an example which uses two path will be more helpful ;)

Comment: Let me update that.